# ¿Qué uso tiene monitorizar etiquetas?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

yo creí que monitorizando una etiqueta me llegaba una notificación cada vez que se formulaba una pregunta con esta etiqueta o algo así, pero veo que no es así, entonces ¿cuál sería su uso?.

Comment: Estaría genial recibir una notificación cuando hicieses login con algo como "Hay 5 nuevas preguntas de [JavaScript] desde la últilma vez que entraste, haz click aqui para verlas"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La herramienta de monitorización de etiquetas te brindan posibilidades como:

- Filtrar preguntas
- Filtrar por etiquetas que pudieran tener subgrupos, por ejemplo:

  - mi-etiqueta-fav-1
  - mi-etiqueta-fav-1-1

De modo que tal vez no tengo intención de estar haciendo *scroll* en todo el listado de preguntas que aparecen por que:

- No tengo conocimiento en otros lenguajes
- No tengo interés en participar en las preguntas que pertenezcan a otras etiquetas
- Dentro de los subgrupos que puede tener una tecnología, solo quiero filtrar por aquellas preguntas que se ajusten a mi búsqueda de versión: **tecnología-1-x**

Entonces cuando ingresamos del lado izquierdo a la opción **Preguntas** en el menú superior nos da la opción de filtrar:

- Mas reciente
- Activas
- Aquellas que tienen una recompensa
- Que no poseen respuesta
- El apartado de **Mas** te va a permitir aplicar los filtros que guardes, los cuales van a obtener las preguntas en función de la etiqueta que le asignaste a cada uno de llos

Uno de los puntos fuertes precisamente de esta herramienta va directamente ligado al buen uso que demos al respecto de etiquetar las preguntas ya que con base en ello nuestros filtros funcionarán de forma mas efectiva ayudando a que encontremos aquellos recursos que nos interesa.

Todo lo anterior para.....

Considera que tenemos tecnologías como:

- Python
- Laravel
- PHP
- etc.

Donde cada una de ellas tiene diferentes versiones, que si las publicaciones están bien etiquetadas nos van a ayudar a filtrar mas rápido para depurar

Finalmente cuando estás revisando el listado de preguntas, fácilmente puedes aplicar dicho filtro buscando del lado derecho en la parte media algo como lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Si después de un periodo de tiempo se anexan preguntas sobre tu tu filtro personalizado que aún no revisas, entonces:

- Un círculo rojo a lado izquierdo del nombre de tu filtro aparecerá indicando contenido nuevo
- Cuando le des click te llevará a las preguntas que se corresponden a dicho filtro y las que son *nuevas* aparecerán en el listado con un círculo rojo a lado izquierdo del nombre de la misma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]